# Magic underwater bike?

Tags: story-identification

For some time now I have been trying to recall a book my father gave me as a teen. It was about a boy who received a bicycle that could ride underwater, allowing him to breathe and perform normal actions. I don't remember much else about the story except the "magic" bike.

Can anyone help in identifying this story, as I would love to share this book with my kids.

Answer (score 8):

### Sounds like [*Mercycle*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/604998.Mercycle) by Piers Anthony.

The main conceit is a set of bicycles which move their riders partially into an alternate universe without oceans, allowing them to explore the sea floor of our planet while being mostly subjected to the physical reality of the alternate planet.

However, since it's Piers Anthony you may want to review it before sharing it with your kids; he's got some controversial notions of sexuality and gender roles which he discusses pretty explicitly. I would want to go in prepared to talk about them if I were in your position.

Comment: That is it! I should have guessed it was Piers Anthony my Dad gave me many of his books to read.  I just googled the cover and it immediately came rushing back.  Thank you so very much.  As for my "kids" I probably should have mentioned that both are in their late teens early twenties so its not really an issue.  Now I have to find a copy as I would also love to read it again. I have been trying to remember the name of that for years now so this is awesome!

Comment: @Ronnie Kinda late, but just in case you ever come back to this: please do mark BESW's answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark on the left. It marks the question solved and is a nice way of thanking him for solving your problem.